# HTTP with username password authentication and XML parsing iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to download data from HTTP using username and password for authentication using objective-c. And want to download the data which will be returned. And want to parse it for usage, like if the data gets downloaded successfully a new screen will be opened and if data could not be downloaded it would take me to another screen.

Please let me know if there is any full tutorial related to this or let me know how can I do this .. ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular service you have in mind? There is more than one way this can be done, and it depends on the server behavior. Or do you have design control over the server operation?

Comment: Actually I want to use nsurlconnection for this purpose. And the service to which I want to get connected and receive the data, will send me an xml file.. I have searched a lot but haven't got any solution ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the connection delegate

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
    // To get into a new view controller. Push the newviewcontroller with the help of navigation controller.
    }
```

and use the parsing delegate

```
 - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {

    //To use the parsing data to be displayed in other view controller.Push the Otherviewcontroller with the help of navigation controller.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out Apple's SeismicXML code, it is really simple to follow and uses classes native to apple. In this example, an RSS feed is downloaded and displayed by parsing the XML. I am using this modified code to query Amazon and download product information. Check it out here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have checked it but it does not works the way I need to. I want to send Username and password to the specific URL and It should be get connected and send the data to my app. And after receiving the data further action of going to another view should be done

Comment: @OmerKhan Does the website that you want to login to have an API? I am not 100% positive, but until a website has an API to send and receive information from it, I think it's impossible.